# Inserting HTML table into page after converting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I am trying to display a HTML table on a page within my flask app after converting it from a pandas dataframe. The app starts by getting three variables from drop menus on the 'home' page and then creates a data frame depending on these (web scrapes certain data from a URL based on selection).

I then save the df as a pickle file once the submit button is clicked (which also changes the page) on the homepage so it can be opened and converted to a HTML table on another page...

Below is my show_results method that calls fetch results (this is where the dataframe is pickled) within and then returns the template before trying to add the table:

```
def show_results():
    fetch_results()
    return render_template("get_results.html")
    cache_dir = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "cache")
    cache_file = os.path.join(cache_dir, "file.p")
    if request.method == "POST":
        with open(cache_file, "rb") as fid:
            results = pickle.load(fid)
        results_table = results.to_html()
    print(results_table)
```

My general idea was to return the template then add the table to it after...

At the moment, get_results.html just has a navbar and a header. I tried following the GeeksForGeeks tutorial:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-to_html-method/

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the dataframe to the template html as a table such as :

```
@app.route('/dropDownVals', methods=['GET' ,'POST'])
def getDropDownVals():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Casa.db")
    df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT TEAMA FROM [TABLE]

    UNION 

    SELECT DISTINCT TEAMB FROM [TABLE]
    ) AS X
    WHERE TEAMA NOT LIKE '%#%'
    ORDER BY 1""", conn)
    c = conn.cursor()
    conn.commit()  # commit needed
    c.close()
    return render_template('findCollisions.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data', header="true")], titles=df.columns.values)
```

Then on the template page you can pick up those values by using [Jinja](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/) templating :

```
 {% for table in tables %}
 {{titles[loop.index]}}
 {{ table|safe }}
 {% endfor %}
```